# How to rollback transaction in Grails integration tests on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

How I can (should) configure Grails integration tests to rollback transactions automatically when using MongoDB as datasource?
(I'm using Grails 2.2.1 + mongodb plugin 1.2.0)

Answer (score 2):

For spock integration tests I defined a MongoIntegrationSpec that gives some control of cleaning up test data.

- dropDbOnCleanup = true // will drop the entire DB after every feature method is executed.
- dropDbOnCleanupSpec = true // will drop the entire DB after after the spec is complete.
- dropCollectionsOnCleanup = ["collectionA", "collectionB", ...] // drops collections after every feature method is executed.
- dropCollectionsOnCleanupSpec = ["collectionA", "collectionB", ...] // drops collections after the spec is complete.
- dropNewCollectionsOnCleanup = true // after every feature method is executed, all new collections are dropped
- dropNewCollectionsOnCleanupSpec = true // after the spec is complete, all new collections are dropped

Here's the source

https://github.com/onetribeyoyo/mtm/tree/dev/src/test/integration/com/onetribeyoyo/util/MongoIntegrationSpec.groovy

And the project has a couple usage examples too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's even possible, because MongoDB doesn't support transactions.  You could use suggested `static transactional = 'mongo'`, but it helps only if you didn't flush your data (it's rare situation I think)

Instead you could cleanup database on `setUp()` manually. You can drop collection for a domain that you're going to test, like:

```
MyDomain.collection.drop()
```

and (optinally) fill with all data require for your test.

Comment: Using DomainObject.collection.drop() in a tearDown() method worked.  Previously I had tried DomainObject.deleteAll() and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can use `static transactional = 'mongo'` in `integration` test and/or `service` class.
Refer [MongoDB Plugin](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/5.%20Transactions.html) for more details.

Comment: "static transactional = 'mongo'" indide integration tests doesn't help. BTW, there is not information about integration tests in MongoDB plugin docs.

Comment: Have you also tried using `disconnect()` in the `tearDown()`?

Comment: No. Have you? Which class/object I should use to call disconnect()? How it's related to transactions?

Comment: I meant `tearDown()` method in integration test. Have a look at the example mentioned in the Unit Testing page which used `DatastoreUnitTestMixin` for Grails 1.3.x. Earlier version of grails Unit tests used to `extend GroovyTestCase`. It is stricter in newer versions. Int Tests on other hand extends `GroovyTestCase`. Look at the `tearDown()` method in the example. Try to implement the same in  your integration test. I apologize I wont be able to try and test it immediately now but will do once I access my machine. :)

Comment: Few things to note as well: 1. Service classes are `transactional` so your transaction logic should be in grails `service` layer. 2. Look at the transaction page of the plugin docs. 3. Throwing an `Exception` out of the grails `service` class back to the callee "rollsback" `transactions` as well.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not support transactions! And hence you cannot use it. The options you have are

#### 1. Go around and drop the collections for the DomainClasses you used.

```
MyDomain.collection.drop() //If you use mongoDB plugin alone without hibernate
MyDomain.mongo.collection.drop() //If you use mongoDB plugin with hibernate
```

**Draw back is you have to do it for each domain you used**

#### 2. Drop the whole database (You don't need to create it explicitly, but you can)

```
String host = grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo.host
Integer port = grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo.port
Integer databaseName = grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo.databaseName

def mongo = new GMongo(host, port)
mongo.getDB(databaseName).dropDatabase() //this takes 0.3-0.5 seconds in my machin
```

The second option is easier and faster. To make this work for all your tests, extend `IntegrationSpec` and add the code to drop the database in the cleanup block (I am assuming you are using Spock test framework) or do a similar thing for JUnit like tests!

Hope this helps!